# Is the current world more likely under determinism than indeterminism?

Tags: determinism

I suppose this may be an obvious quip, but according to Bayesian confirmation theory, evidence E confirms a theory A over theory B if it is more expected under theory A.

If determinism is true, and we take E to be the current state of affairs of the world, then it follows that this E is expected given a particular initial condition that leads to this E. In other words, P (E|determinism and a particular initial condition that leads to E) is 1. Now, there may be many possible initial events, but let’s assume that this initial event is necessary. Now, given any particular initial state, if the universe is indeterministic, then E is very unlikely. And if at every little moment, reality picks one of many branches as quantum mechanics seems to suggest, then P(E|indeterminism given any initial state) is exceptionally low.

So from a Bayesian perspective, would it be fair to say that determinism confirms the evidence more than indeterminism?

Comment: Like most such questions, instead of asking about the world, asking about algorithms and computers is sufficient and less confusing.

Comment: If you have a theory that successfully duplicates the stochastic predictions of quantum mechanics, but allows deterministic predictions, hasten to a reputable physics journal and get the ball rolling on your Nobel prize. Future generations of undergrads will grumble as they memorize equations bearing your surname. 

If you don't have a deterministic theory that successfully duplicates the stochastic predictions of quantum mechanics, there is no theory B, so the question is irrelevant.

Comment: Surely the probability of us having ended up here is 1 regardless of which route we took. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @MarcoOcram the probability as calculated from BEFORE now. Probably better phrased as, the probability from the point of view of someone calculating the probability at the beginning of the universe. The probability we end up here is not 1 from that perspective in the indeterministic case.

Comment: `Now, there may be many possible initial events, but let’s assume that this initial event is necessary.` - I don't know that this is a fair assumption.

Answer (score 1):

> So from a Bayesian perspective, would it be fair to say that determinism confirms the evidence more than indeterminism?

It's easier to consider a smaller scale than the world. Imagine 2 tv screens. One of the screens shows atmospheric noise, which can be regarded as indeterministic, let's say for the sake of discussion. The other tv screen shows a recording of atmospheric noise from a DVD. This means it's fully determined input.

Imagine you don't know which screen you have, but you can take a screenshot of the screen as evidence. Does this help you to determine if that screen shows the live noise or recorded noise?

In itself the screenshot is evidence for neither. Only if you knew the record that one of the screens is showing so that you could map the screenshot to a time on the DVD could you be pretty sure that that screen is the one showing a recording.

For the universe it is quite impossible to fully predict later states from initial states for multiple possible reasons (Several of which also apply to deterministic universes). So any given state cannot be compared to any predicted state with perfect accuracy to tell the universe is deterministic.

So bayesian theory is likely wrongly applied here, though I cannot tell more precisely the flaws.

However, when not making exact predictions, but rough predictions like "There is a 90% chance of rain tomorrow", we can see that the universe behaves "deterministic enough" for many purposes. Maybe this common sense can also be expressed with probability theory.

Comment: Plus 1 for a lovely analogy!

Answer (score -2):

Determinism is not a thing of reality.  Determinism is only a theoretical idea of a system very much different from reality.

Therefore reality is indeterministic by definition, not by any conclusion.

Comment: That is a nice assertion but where is your proof? Secondly, the truth of determinism is irrelevant to the question I just asked if you pay attention. The question is about whether the current state of affairs is likely or unlikely **given** a certain theory.

Comment: The current state of affairs is not evidence of either determinism or indeterminism. Neither is a theory. Under indeterminism the current state evolved from singularity, an initial state of zero entropy. Under determinism the current state would require one particular ready-made initial state with equal entropy, the "necessary initial event". Under determinism such an initial state cannot evolve or be created.

Comment: The reasoning is in the right direction so +1. But you should either remove the 'therefore' (2nd para). Or add more explanation.

Comment: Why? If determinism ≠ reality by definition, then reality ≠ determinism by the same definition.

Comment: `Therefore reality is indeterministic by definition` that's not a very good definition then.

Comment: @TKoL The definition of determinism is a good one. Universally accepted, but sadly often misunderstood.  As determinism differs from reality by this definition, reality differs from determinism by the same definition.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki it's really weird to talk about these definitions as much as you are without actually saying what they are and how you think they contradict. Your post really ought to be more explicit - if it's indeterministic by definition, what are these definitions?

Comment: @TKoL There is  only one definition and everyone should be aware of it. Here is the SEP wording: "Causal determinism is, roughly speaking, the idea that every event is necessitated by antecedent events and conditions together with the laws of nature."

Comment: And what's the definition of 'reality'?

Comment: @TKoL Look around. What you see is reality. Read some facts. They tell you more about reality.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki you are not making a very compelling case about what you said is true 'by definition'. If I have to look around at reality to discover that it's not deterministic, then the fact that it's not deterministic is not true 'by definition', it's true by empirical evidence. That would be a much more effective argument for you to make than 'by definition'

Comment: @TKoL Your task is to compare determinism and reality and notice that they are not the same. Reality does not meet the definition of determinism. If it did, there would be no need for a definition.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki that's not what it means, in English, to say something is true 'by definition'. If you've discovered that reality is not deterministic by observing the world, then you haven't discovered it's true BY DEFINITION, you've discovered it's true empirically. Using the phrase "by definition" is not communicating what you actually think. You will improve your philosophical communications if you adjust your phrasing.

Comment: @TKoL This is not at all an empirical thing. It's all about the definition. Determinism is different from reality by definition. If it wasn't, there would be no need to define the concept of determinism at all. The description of determinism would be just another law of nature describing reality.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki okay, keep using words incorrectly, that's fine too.

Comment: @TKoL Please, explain. What words did I use incorrectly?

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki if you are saying something is true "by definition", but your method of finding out it was true was by observing the world and looking at the world, then you don't know it's true 'by definition', you know it's true by empiricism and observation.

Comment: If it were true by definition, then you would be easily able to show where the definition of reality conflicts with the definition of determinism. But instead of doing that, you just say "Look around. What you see is reality. Read some facts." That's not good enough. That's not an argument

Comment: @TKoL Apparently you didn't get it. If determinism were true (=a property of reality), there would be no need to define the concept at all. The fact that we need to define such a concept proves that it is not an observable property of reality.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki and you don't say the same of indeterminism? If indeterminism were true, there would be no need to define the concept at all. That proves it's not an observable property of reality. This argument doesn't make sense whatsoever.

Comment: @TKoL Indeterminism is the absence of determinism, which must be defined first.